# Can't enable MySQL 5.6 Query Cache

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I'm trying to enable MySQL Query Cache on **Ubuntu 15.04** with **MySQL 5.6.25**

I've added this to end end of `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf`:

```
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size = 4096M
query_cache_limit = 2M
query_cache_strip_comments =1
```

The whole server has been restarted more than once.

```
user@myhost:/$ mysql
mysql: unknown variable 'query_cache_type=1'
```

Using `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%query_cache%'` confirms that `query_cache_type = OFF`

```
SET GLOBAL query_cache_type = 1;
/* SQL Error (1651): Query cache is disabled; restart the server with query_cache_type=1 to enable it */
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You should have pointed people  to the [other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689132/cant-enable-mysql-5-6-query-cache) on StackOverflow. It saves duplication of effort (plus, it's good manners). -1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't put those lines at the very bottom of the file.

Look for the `[mysqld]` group header in `my.cnf` and put those lines under it

```
[mysqld]
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size = 4096M
query_cache_limit = 2M
query_cache_strip_comments =1
```

Those line cannot go under any other group header.

Then, restart mysqld.

Comment: The configuration file I had was malformed. I got a fresh one and placed things in the right place, which fixed the issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

4GB for the query cache?  NO, NO.

That will slow down your system.

Every change to a table requires scanning the 4GB to purge entries for that table.

Limit the value to, say, 50M.